What is the difference between Starlink Roam and Starlink Boats?
When buying Starlink, I can choose between three offers:

residential
roam
boats

While I understand that "residential" means it will be restricted to the service address I used to sign up, I still wonder about the difference between "roam" and "boats".
Will I be restricted to specific areas on the earth's surface when choosing "roam" and will I be restricted to the open sea when I choose "boats".
This is specifically interesting when looking at countries, where Starlink is restricted, such as for example in Turkey:

If I sign up for "roam" and go on a hiking trip in Turkey, will I have service or not?
If I sign up for "boat" and I pass the Bosporus or I stay in the Golden Horn, will I have service or not?

Is there any known restriction that with "roam" or "boat" I will have to move? Like if I stay with a mobile home for 2-3 weeks in the same location, will that be considered an abuse of "roam"?

I’m voting to close this question because it is about starlink tos, not travel

@littleadv about tos doesn't imply it's not about travel. E.g., we don't close questions whose answers are in airlines tos.

Why was this question on the difference between Starlink Roam and Starlink Boats closed?

@FranckDernoncourt airline tos are relevant to travel. This is not.

@littleadv Having Internet access traveling is relevant to traveling. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet

Interpretation of laws and contracts is more suitable for law@se. The question is not about having anything, it's about interpretation of a contract.

@littleadv more suitable somewhere else (which I disagree in this case btw) doesn't mean it's off-topic here.

More suitable there than anywhere else doesn't mean it's suitable at all here. Should we do contract review for anything that is tangentially related to travel? We shouldn't do contract review at all, IMHO.

If this is not travel-related I wonder what is. Please let’s not close questions just for the sake of closing them. Voting to reopen.

Starlink residential would be off topic, but the roaming and boat versions are specifically for travelling. And the question which version would be best for which kind of travel also fits this site.


What is the difference between Starlink Roam and Starlink Boats?

Only boats allow ocean use. Note that Starlink Roam does allow coast use, which means up to 12 nautical miles from land (~=22km), as Midavalo commented, up to 5 consecutive days at a time and a total of 60 days over the course of a year.

will I be restricted to the open sea when I choose "boats".

No, land is ok too. From https://www.starlink.com/support/article/952e770f-570e-d984-5014-35ae2add51c7

The Mobile Priority service plan enables our fastest network speeds for consumers and can be used on the ocean and land, and is available in 50GB, 1TB, and 5TB plans. Order now from starlink.com/boats. Starlink for business use, visit starlink.com/business/maritime. Starlink for business use have Mobile Priority tiers available in 50GB, 1TB, 5TB, 10TB, 15TB, and Unlimited.

https://www.starlink.com/service-plans gives a good recap for personal plans:


Note that Starlink ToS keep changing and have many subtleties, e.g. see https://www.rvmobileinternet.com/starlink-makes-further-changes-to-roam-plans-that-impacts-boaters-cruisers/ (mirror 1, mirror 2).

Roam allows use up to 12 nautical miles from the coast

@Midavalo yes that falls under coastal use. https://www.rvmobileinternet.com/starlink-makes-further-changes-to-roam-plans-that-impacts-boaters-cruisers/ I linked to  gives more details on it, notably "New changes to Starlink's terms for the Roam service plan will soon limit "Coastal Coverage" to "5 consecutive days at a time and a total of 60 days over the course of a year."
